# How i can fix user.remove_roles error at register command?

Tags: python, discord.py

This is my code:

```
@Bot.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@has_permissions(change_nickname=True)
async def e(ctx, user:discord.User, isim, yas):
    nickname = isim + " | " + yas
    await user.remove_roles(discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Unregistered"))
    await user.add_roles(discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name='Boy'))
    await user.edit(nick=nickname)
```

I tried place print(1) between each code and it stops when it comes to:

```
await user.remove_roles(discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Unregistered"))
```

What is error in there?

Comment: But what’s the error????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`discord.User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20user#discord.User) objects don't have `remove_roles`, `add_roles` or `edit` methods.

What you actually want is a [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) object:

```py
@Bot.command()
@commands.guild_only()
@has_permissions(change_nickname=True)
async def e(ctx, user: discord.Member, isim, yas):
    nickname = isim + " | " + yas
    unregistered = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Unregistered")
    boy = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name='Boy')

    await user.remove_roles(unregistered)
    await user.add_roles(boy)
    await user.edit(nick=nickname)
```

A `discord.User` isn't guild specific, it represents a Discord user, as opposed to `discord.Member`, which is guild specific and represents a guild member.